# How to make CardContent height response depending on its contents

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react. I've been trying different components such as Grid component but the height responsiveness doesn't seem to work if its inside in a CardContent. Now im trying Stack component. Is there a way that my Stack will do a new line in the CardContent if my Chip component overflows horizontally instead of making a horizontal scroll? Im also okay if the solution used Grid component

[image]

My code is something like this

```
<Card sx={{mt: 1, mb: 1}}>
<CardHeader
    sx={{pt: .5, pb: .5}}
    action={
        <Button>Add Person (WIP)</Button>
    }
/>

<CardContent sx={{pt: .5, pb: .5, overflow: 'auto'}}>
    <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
        {
            <>
            <Chip label="Person Name"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name2"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name3"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name4"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name5"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name6"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name7"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name8"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name9"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name10"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name11"/>
            <Chip label="Person Name12"/>
            </>
        }
    </Stack>
</CardContent>
```

Comment: You should try using [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap).

Comment: I tried adding "<CardContent sx={{pt: .5, pb: .5,flexWrap: 'flex'}}>" or "<Stack direction="row" spacing={1} sx={{flexWrap: 'flex'}}>" still nothing changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `flexWrap:wrap` to Stack component.

like this:

```
 <Stack direction="row"  style={{flexWrap:'wrap'}} spacing={1}>
```

or add   flexWrap="wrap" as prop to it

```
 <Stack direction="row" flexWrap="wrap" spacing={1}>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-vaughan-8k482t?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This works for me. The multiple stack is now adjusting to the CardContent components width. One last thing what am I missing because the CardContent height is still not responsive (adjusting). I already added a display:flex to the CardContent  component but no luck

Comment: I didn't get, what wrong is  with height !

Comment: Sorry for my explanation.. The second row of stack component only displays half of it. The CardContent still doesn't adjust to its item size.

Comment: aha, I'm trying in codesandbox and it's working fine, but maybe adding minHeight:'fit-content' to CardContent will fix your problem

Comment: if still not working please provide more information or make codesandbox for it, I will fix it

Comment: I've tried adding minHeight and it works. I really appreciate I'm fairly new to frontend

Comment: aha, happy to hear that :)

Comment: btw can you explain why we used style not sx in this component?

Comment: yes, sx is mui syntax to style component and when you use style it will apply style to the parent element, not to what mui apply

Comment: but now I made a mistake here, there is no difference bettween using sx or style (both works the same )

Comment: for mui component it's better to use sx, but sometimes  style might help you as trick to add special style